# Unwanted automatically changed MAC address almost every boot

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

On a Windows 10 notebook since some weeks the MAC address of the integrated Intel 3165 Wifi card changes almost every (re)boot. I could not find settings to fix it.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling Settings->Network & Internet->WiFi->"Random hardware addresses" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, I only looked in the drivers section and haven't thought that it could be a "feature" of windows. IMO it does not make sense for a "private" network and should not be enabled by default.